# WPF resizing a canvas doesn't work in dispatcher

Tags: wpf, dispatcher, rendertransform

I am trying to resize a canvas using the following code but in the dispatcher. It doesn't seems to work am I missing something?

```
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
                        canvas.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(scale, 
scale);
                        canvas.Measure(new Size(scale * w, scale * h));
                        canvas.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, scale * w, scale * 
h));
                        canvas.UpdateLayout();

                        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(scale * w, scale * h, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
                        rtb.Render(canvas);
                }), DispatcherPriority.Send);

            }
```

Comment: @Clemens okay that may be redundant - my question is that if this works normally why wouldn't it work when I put it in a background worker and use dispatcher (I do this because rendering to a rendertargetbitmap takes time and I don't want to freeze my UI)

Comment: How should anybody know that, when you don't show the relevant parts of your code? How are you using the Dispatcher?

Comment: @Clemens I edited my question added some more code. Basically I save my canvases into a queue and render them one by one in the main window and save the resultant to jpeg

Comment: So what exactly does it mean when you say "*it doesn't work*"? I have still no idea what your code is supposed to do. All I can say is that applying a RenderTransform seems entirely pointless, when you want to resize the Canvas by regular layout. You should remove it.

Comment: I also think that setting DispatcherPriority.Send is pointless. Remove that too, or use Normal.

Comment: @Clemens The size doesn't change

Comment: But the size of the RenderTargetBitmap is what you expect?

Comment: @Clemens Yeah, the original size of the canvas is w and h, I then multiply it by the scale say 3 or 4, the canvas does not resize and remains at w and h size so the rendertargetbitmap is mostly blank

Comment: And how do you realize that the Canvas is not resized? Does it have a Background Brush, or are you expecting that its child elements get scaled? Please also tell us more about the actual content of the Canvas. What is it that you are rendering there? Maybe you're on the wrong track altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create a bitmap from a Canvas with a scaled size you do not need to resize or scale the Canvas.

Just create a VisualBrush from the Canvas and draw an appropriately sized rectangle with it into a DrawingVisual. Using a DrawingVisual also avoids any potential problems with margins and alignments.

```
var width = canvas.ActualWidth * scale;
var height = canvas.ActualHeight * scale;
var visual = new DrawingVisual();

using (var dc = visual.RenderOpen())
{
    dc.DrawRectangle(new VisualBrush(canvas), null, new Rect(0, 0, width, height));
}

var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)width, (int)height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
rtb.Render(visual);
```

Comment: the problem with visual brush is it makes the image in the canvas blurry. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Which image? Are there any Image elements in the Canvas?

Comment: Yes, the canvas contains an image.

Comment: Try to set a BitmapScalingMode: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.renderoptions.setbitmapscalingmode?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I have set it to Fant but it doesn't help. A figured out from a little research that I'm trying to draw a big image with a small pen so the result is blurry.

Comment: "*big image with a small pen*" - sorry, but that doesn't sound like it would make much sense. However, since you haven't shown *anything* about this Image in a Canvas, it is hard to help. Maybe you write another question with all relevant details.